# Java regex not working to find "Ts" followed by "kb"

Tags: java, regex

I have to convert "Tskb" to "TsKB" using java regex whenever it comes as single word. I have written below code which not working.

```
    public class TestBGR {
    private static final Pattern s_TsKB = Pattern.compile("/(Ts?.*)(?=.*kb)^(\\w+)$/");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Tskb";
        Matcher       matcher = s_TsKB.matcher(text);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
        int           offset  = 0;

        while (matcher.find())
        {
        String replacement = "KB";      
        builder.replace(matcher.start() + offset, matcher.end() + offset,
                        replacement);       
        offset += replacement.length() - matcher.group().length();
        }       
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}
```

Here how to find "Ts" followed by "kb" using java regex..?

Comment: Did you consider a simple `text = text.replaceAll("\\bTskb\\b", "TsKB");`? Note you are using regex delimiters that cannot be used in Java regex pattern (as they are treated as literal `/`). Looking at your example result, I think the question is "how to find `kb` preceded with `Ts`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a `replaceAll` with

```
(?<=\\bTs)kb\\b
```

and replace by `KB`.The lookbehind will make sure `kb` has `Ts` before.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/13

Comment: Well the the solution is perfect, but as I'm checking this regex against XML format its giving me "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."

I can't use "<", Is there any other work around which i could use in place of "<"

Comment: can't use this because above mentioned String "replacement = "  is calculated based on some API which will make upper case only the substring present at XX mentioned in "(?<=\\bTs)XX\\b"

Comment: @RajBhatia can you try `\\b(Ts)kb\\b` and replace with `$1KB`

Comment: @vks- Sir this isn't working as there is method to calculate replacement which take matcher.start() and matcher.end().
String replacement = getRepl(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), matcher);

For that i need to fix this "<" special character

Comment: @RajBhatia you can probably ask this as a new question with this regex as there is no straight forward method.Probably some regex aficionado in java can suggest something :)

Comment: yes its not right platform to ask other problem, but i have got the solution by replacing "<" with "&lt;" and it worked. Thnx a lot to correct my regex :) :)

Comment: @RajBhatia cool....in that case you can modify my answer to add urs as well for future visitors :)